# jQuery DataTable has no search box

Tags: jquery, datatables

This may be a simple question but I have no idea as to what I'm supposed to do to have the search box at the top of the grid.

This is what I got:

```
var table = $('#tblCountries').DataTable({
   "filter": false,
   "pagingType": "simple_numbers",
   "orderClasses": false,
   "order": [[0, "asc"]],
   "info": false,
   "scrollY": "450px",
   "scrollCollapse": true,
   "bProcessing": true,
   "bServerSide": true,
   "sAjaxSource": "DataWebService.asmx/GetTableData",
   "fnServerData": function(sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
       aoData.push({ "name": "roleId", "value": "admin" });
       $.ajax({
           "dataType": 'json',
           "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
           "type": "GET",
           "url": sSource,
           "data": aoData,
           "success": function(msg) {
               var json = jQuery.parseJSON(msg.d);
               fnCallback(json);
               $("#tblCountries").show();
           },
           error: function(xhr, textStatus, error) {
               if (typeof console == "object") {
                   console.log(xhr.status + "," + xhr.responseText + "," + textStatus + "," + error);
               }
           }
       });
   },
   fnDrawCallback: function() {
       $('.image-details').bind("click", showDetails);
   }
});
```

The datatable works well with the data and pagination but no search box.

Comment: Please make a jsfiddle

Comment: Could `"filter": false,` be the reason for the missing search box?  How are you handling the paging in your server-side code?

Comment: use  "filter": true,  instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"filter": true,` this handles the search box in Datatables. [Reference](http://legacy.datatables.net/ref#bFilter)

If `filter` doesn't work then try `bFilter`. in current version of Datatables it is `bFilter` and its default value is true

Comment: ...Or just not set `filter` at all. `bFilter` and `filter` is equal / means the same from 1.10.x, before that only `bFilter` is valid.  But this is only interesting if you want to remove search box.

Comment: @davidkonrad i agree with you if you don't set it will get displayed by default.

Comment: Thanks Santosh. That answers my question. But before I mark that as answer, I noticed it doesn't filter the grid when I use it. The grid just remains the same. Any suggestions?

Comment: @KaceyEzerioha you are using server side processing so you have filter the data from backend this is what  `HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["sSearch"];` i am using to get the search text .

Comment: @giuseppe This was almost 3 years back. It looks like it got deprecated. But am sure you can find something similar to this in official docs

Comment: yes in fact you are right, reading well the doc solved my issue. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If this is server-side processing and new version of data table then use:

```
searching: true,
```